# How to open .theme file

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate, extension, drupal

I am using Ubuntu MATE 16.04. How can I open **.theme** file in drupal 8 ?.

[image: Click Here]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try through a terminal

```
$ gksu pluma /var/www/html/cms/drupal8/core/themes/bartik/bartik.theme
```

Comment: Currently it's working fine in **cmd** prompt. But, I need  permanent solution.

Comment: @tamilselvan What about right clicking on the file, choosing open with other application, and then choosing Pluma Text Editor there.

Comment: Please see my update.